# How to change background color of jquery mobile page?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to change the background color of the jquery mobile 1.4.5 pages. I have google around and found what some people suggest as the correct css overrides to do this.  However, nothing works for me.

My CSS overrides are the last CSS file loaded in my app so I would expect that the below classes override the jqm css but they don't.

Does anybody know the correct way to do it?

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/f5ta4dyw/1/)

**UPDATE:**
See updated fiddle.

CSS:

```
.ui-page {
      background:#296BC1;
}
.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper
.ui-content {
     background:#296BC1;
}
```

Comment: add !important in .ui-page background property

Comment: Thanks. As you can see I'm not very strong in CSS.  I forgot about the !important.  I updated the fiddle with the CSS that works for my app.  However, I noticed the jsfiddle's background color only is changed for 'div' area in the content section.  Not the entire space between the header and footer.  I'm not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
.ui-overlay-a,
.ui-page-theme-a,
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
.ui-page{
    background-color: #faaaff !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div[data-role=page][data-theme=a] {
    background:#fff;
}
```